# How to show autcmd errors on another window?

Tags: autocmd

I've got this command that's run before write, which formats my Elixir code, however the error is also shown in the same buffer(?) or the same window, so the window gets messed up as a result.

```
augroup foo
  " Remove all vimrc autocommands
  autocmd!
  au BufWritePre */*.ex,*/*.exs silent !mix format %
augroup END
```

How can I have the errors shown in another window?

Comment: What is that `-q` argument?   That will cause an error.   If it's for quiet, the `silent` command prefix is good.

Comment: Oh sorry that `-q` was my experiment. I simply forgot to remove it later and as you mentioned I was getting errors. :) Thank you! I've edited my post now.

Comment: Is this plugin useful?  https://github.com/mhinz/vim-mix-format

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to achieve and what I was looking for. Thank you! When there's any problem with the format now I see the error in location window. I wonder how they've achieved that. Maybe the difference is that this is a plugin and I was invoking a shell command? I'll have to take a look at the code.

Comment: Yes, the plugin code is definitely worth a look.  You can usually do much more versatile things inside custom functions than trying to squeeze into a one-liner.   It's possible that the `system('cmd')` function was used to run a shell command instead of !cmd.   That's usually quieter and you can save the return stdout value to a variable for further work.